# VBA importing values from file deal with dots and commas (thousands and decimals)

Tags: excel, vba, replace, decimal, numeric

I'm having a problem when importing a txt or csv file originated from SAP. Within that file there are columns that have values, most of them integer values, no problem with those. The problem I'm facing is with values that have decimals on them. As an example, I have a column with stock values, those can range from 0,001 to 99 999,999. As I'm in Portugal my decimals/thousants regional settings are " " for the thousands and "," for the decimals. I need to treat all my imported values to be in the same format, but I'm not being able to do so. I've tried several solutions, even solutions already on the stackoverflow, but again, with no success. I've also tried disabling the regional settings and specifying the thousands and decimal separators. There is also another problem, as SAP exports this field (column) always with 10 characters I need to replace the " " for no "" (no spaces), if I do this, the value in it will be already seen as a numeric value and already changes the imported values. I even tried maitaining the spaces for Excel to see the value as a string, and do the replaces of dots and only then remove the spaces, but then, Excel detects both dots and commas as dots. I don't know if it helps but if I do the Find and Replace from the menu in Excel, and select the range, it works fine. If I record a macro with those steps, and then run that same macro, it doesn't work, I get the same strange behaviour and results.

Here are some examples of raw values and how they should be imported:

```txt
Raw Value      Pretended Value
3.655,600      3655,6    (should remove the thousands separator)
10.548         10548     (should remove the thousands separator)
872            872       (once there is no separators, it should do nothing)
1.872          1872      (should remove the thousands separator)
16.000         16000     (should remove the thousands separator)
105,372        105,372   (only decimals separator, it should do nothing)
460,8          460,8     (only decimals separator, it should do nothing)
60,72          60,72     (only decimals separator, it should do nothing)
1.574,400      1574,400  (should remove the thousands separator)
```

Any advise would be helpful.
Thanks in advance,
Jorge Vieira

```
    Columns("M:M").Select
    Selection.Replace What:=".", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False


    Columns("M:M").Select
    Selection.Replace What:=".", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
```

```
3.655,600     3 655 600 (it should be 3655,600)
10.548            10548 (correct)
872                 872 (correct)
1.872              1872 (correct)
16.000            16000 (correct)
105,372          105372 (it should maintain 105,372)
460,8              4608 (it should maintain 105,372)
60,72              6072 (it should maintain 105,372)
1.574,400     1 574 400 (it should be 1574,400)
```

Comment: Are the data wrong imported or is only the formation wrong? How do you open/import the data?

Comment: The formatting is wrong. If I don't do any coding, it imports as a string with spaces to fill the 10 characters.  I import the data with QueryTables.Add.

Comment: You could try to define the thousands separator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.querytable.textfilethousandsseparator

Comment: I've tried that already. I tried it now once more, and it's still not working.

Comment: Forget that, actually it worked. I've been trying so many different solutions, that after importing with QueryTables.Add and setting the thousands and the decimals separator I had one more replace that was converting "." for "", and somehow that was changing the values even though there was no more "." to replace. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= "TEXT; C:\Test\Test.csv", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .TextFileThousandsSeparator = "." 
    .TextFileDecimalSeparator = ","
```